# Groupby dataframe and filter in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my input spark dataframe, Can someone help me with the desired dataframe or atleast the approach .

| unique-id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OAOS-STP |
| 1 | OAOS-nonSTP |
| 1 | manual |
| 2 | OAOS-nonSTP |
| 2 | manual |
| 3 | OAOS-STP |
| 3 | OAOS-nonSTP |
| 4 | OAOS-STP |
| 4 | manual |

The output Dataframe I am expecting:

| unique-id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OAOS-STP |
| 2 | OAOS-nonSTP |
| 3 | OAOS-STP |
| 4 | OAOS-STP |

OAOS-STP > OAOS-nonSTP > manual in order of precedence.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the status is really text ? because text comprehension ordering is not trivial ... 'fourth' comes between 'first' and 'second' for example. If you are trying to oversimplify the problem with dummy data, that's not always a good idea. You should probably present your actual use case

Comment: @Steven, I have changed the status column

Answer (score 2):

You can link status of each row to an integer representing status order using a dictionary and an [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html), then perform a [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) over `unique-id`, aggregating [`min`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.min.html) status order and finally retrieve status from this status order, as follow:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType


status_dict = {'OAOS-STP': 1, 'OAOS-nonSTP': 2, 'manual': 3}


@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def get_status_order(status):
    return status_dict.get(status)


data = input_df.withColumn('status_order', F.struct(get_status_order('status'), F.col('status'))) \
    .groupBy('unique-id') \
    .agg(F.min('status_order').alias('status')) \
    .withColumn('status', F.col('status.status')) \
    .orderBy('unique-id')  # Optional
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use window functions and select the highest value for each unique-key by doing an ordering on the value of status.

PS: I code in scala

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(
  (1, "OAOS-STP"),
  (1, "OAOS-nonSTP"),
  (1, "manual"),
  (2, "OAOS-nonSTP"),
  (2, "manual"),
  (3, "OAOS-STP"),
  (3, "OAOS-nonSTP"),
  (4, "OAOS-STP"),
  (4, "manual")
).toDF("unique-id", "status")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df2 = df.withColumn("lower_status", lower($"status"))
val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("unique-id").orderBy("status")

val df3 = df2
.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1)
.drop("rank")
.drop("lower_status")
```

output of `df3.show(false)` will be

[image: output]

Comment: Hi Vikas, I have updated the status column, can I assign  integer values to status column like you did, do the window function and then drop the values? what do you suggest?

Comment: @vik, doing ordering on numeric values is much easier as for string values the change in case of alphabets (uppercase or lowercase) can make things difficult. Let me try that and see if it will work.

Comment: you can consider all lowercase

Comment: yupp thats what i would do ...its just spawning a cluster on databricks community cloud takes sometime so waiting for it to spawn and test the logic

Comment: @vik, i have updated my response as per your updated values. If the actual dataset has the same values for status, feel free to use the above solution but if in case there are more values than this you may have to tweak the above logic or map status values to numeric values as per precedence.